# Hibernate no arg constructor visibility

Tags: java, hibernate

While going through the Hibernate 3.x document I came to know that we can declare a no arg constructor for our POJOs with private visibility also but the document says that it has limitation:

> The no-argument constructor is a requirement for all persistent
>   classes; Hibernate has to create objects for you, using Java
>   Reflection. The constructor can be private, however package or public
>   visibility is required for runtime proxy generation and efficient data
>   retrieval without bytecode instrumentation.

I am new to Hibernate and trying to understand when the runtime proxy is used and when the bytecode is used and how this works in Hibernate. Also what is the bytecode instrumentation and how it is used in Hibernate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate uses run-time proxy during lazy initialization of a collection or an association to improve the performance. You can read various fetching strategies and their impact [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html)

Bytecode instrumentation is another technique that allows you to modify the byte code i.e. the class file at the time of loading of the class. [this link](http://blog.javabenchmark.org/2013/05/java-instrumentation-tutorial.html) may be helpful.